# How can I create a Pandas datetime from year and dayofyear?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way in Pandas to convert `year` and `dayofyear` columns to a proper `datetime` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can paste the `year` and `dayofyear` columns together and use the format `%Y%j` to convert:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016, 2017], 'dayofyear': [43, 2, 60]})

pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str) + df.dayofyear.astype(str), format = "%Y%j")

#0   2015-02-12
#1   2016-01-02
#2   2017-03-01
#dtype: datetime64[ns]
```